# My scheduled task in ubuntu shown some errors but it worked

Tags: ubuntu, server, cron, netplan

I am new here. So, if there is something absurd in my expression, don't hesitate to let me know. Thanks very much.

## Background

The network of my server(Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS) got wrong sometimes. And I needed to reconnect it using the command below:

```
cp bak/bad.yaml 00-installer-config.yaml
netplan apply
cp bak/good.yaml 00-installer-config.yaml
netplan apply
cd ~/cmd
./nat.sh
```

That was not a good experience, because at least a person should be here in the lab. So I decide to build a scheduled task using `cron`. Below is what I have done.

1. Type `crontab -e` to edit the scheduled tasks of user `root`
2. Add `0 * * * * /etc/cron.d/netfix >> net_crontab 2&>1` to the file, which means execute the shell script `netfix` every hour, and put the stdout into a text file
3. The script `netfix` is below:

```
#!/bin/bash

function network()
{
    local timeout=1
    local target=www.baidu.com
    local ret_code=`curl -I -s --connect-timeout ${timeout} ${target} -w %{http_code} | tail -n1`

    if [ "x$ret_code" = "x200" ]; then
        return 1
    else
        return 0
    fi

    return 0
}

now=$(date +"%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S")
network
if [ $? -eq 0 ];then
        echo "$now network error"
        cd /etc/netplan
        cp bak/bad.yaml 00-installer-config.yaml
        netplan apply
        cp bak/good.yaml 00-installer-config.yaml
        netplan apply
        cd /home/qiuzw/cmd
        ./nat.sh
        # exit -1
fi

echo "$now network ok"
exit 0
```

## Problem

I didn't meet the previous problem during the whole Spring Festival! But I check the result file `net_crontab`, and there are some errors.

```
...
20230124 04:00:01 network ok
20230124 05:00:01 network error
/etc/cron.d/netfix: line 33: netplan: command not found
/etc/cron.d/netfix: line 35: netplan: command not found
./nat.sh: 3: iptables: not found
./nat.sh: 5: iptables: not found
./nat.sh: 6: iptables: not found
./nat.sh: 7: iptables: not found
20230124 05:00:01 network ok
20230124 06:00:01 network ok
...
```

## Question

So my question is:
Why is the network in `20230124 06:00` is ok, if the command `netplan` is not found?

Some information:

1. I execute `which netplan` in `bash shell` with user `root`, and it works.
2. The `netfix` shell did not check the network after reconnecting it, so `20230124 05:00:01 network ok` should be challenged.
3. Which location shall I put the script `netfix` in? Is `/etc/cron.d` acceptable?

Thanks again for giving me some advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, the answer is 'using absolute path of commands'.

For example, use `/usr/sbin/netplan apply` instead of `netplan apply`.

Interesting~